# Type inference of Function composition method (chain) in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, function, functional-programming, function-composition

I try to implement a function that is to extend a specified function to have **a chainable method for [function composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition)**; as below;

Also see:
**[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/ATDeCgRBjB7A7AzgF2AMWAXmAHgCoA0wAqgHwAUAZgFzDkCGteAlFqSa5uxJFCMgE8ADgFN0WMLz4xYAWyGxEI2jgBqRCgHNa5AEa1indqqN1yDJqZPAAZOmYBuKVAC%20T5yABOI5AFdP8MAA8roAViLQyAB0ACYilACW8CIACp6wop6CVEQARHDyiiK5RBDSUHDwiZr%209LoANsrAyJ6%20IgQeUABu9PVtKupaOvocbMDWXOjmjMAsY5pUDMzLnS6s9IhmM3OThrbonc5u4M6VKMCUAIwSFsDwvrK6Ip6m9MAA1MCXTnxnqJQAJhuM3uj2eryiyFgAGUWkkFo5Tghzgk4vBkAlBBJ8AQKNtXj8oAB6IkAWnJFMpVOpNMpSKQqDQQOwaCoAMRfBJW1ooKeLzGKE88NYdgwwC5mlgsBi9POaEuzKmV2YUQKCiUbI5xKJ3LuDz5pkFwv2YolUplnLJtOtNrpv2RjIBCRuTJVaqK5FRInRmIEWpAXOmPP14IFcPgmhF4nFOsl0tl-wVzuw5Hl7NVcnVIk9aIxgn9Md1vNDk2L-NFAZ1unoMRAAHcABYCAD8zecJNtnetCYuCWuLJz3rzfozhQ1ysJAYAVM1EOQAQBmAAsAFZWM90p5OgBBTw1WRD4CwSjNYRiADktzLpjL5%20ACU28FgqA2iASmngdUazVgwCE9E8egD2QZ4jxPQRRGAS8Rl8eAAGsnzreAbxDTxzyiTo%20DwM9NmPP8AKAnxnk2c96Dveh4Frc9dHI7x73gNV6AxBoRAw8pymwyDz1ghDYCQu8HzuZ9gFfd9PxYn9Ty4282KgTo-guS4dBBVCULBLc%20CnIleBcIA)**

```
{
  const F = <T, U>(f: (a: T) => U) => {
    type F = {
      compose: <V, >(g: (b: U) => V) => (((a: T) => V) & F);
    };
    return Object.defineProperty(f, "compose", {
      configurable: true,
      value: <V,>(g: (b: U) => V) => F((a: T) => g(f(a)))
    }) as ((a: T) => U) & F
  };
  //--------------------------------
  const f1 = (a: number) => a + 1;
  const f2 = (a: number) => a.toString();
  const identity = <T,>(a: T) => a;
  //--------------------------------
  const F2 = F(f2);
  // ((a: number) => string) & F  // good
  const F12 = F(f1).compose(f2);
  // ((a: number) => string) & F  // good
  //--------------------------------
  const F2i = (F2).compose(identity);
  // ((a: number) => string) & F  // good
  const f12i = (F12).compose(identity);
  // ((a: number) => number) & F  // bad  why??
  //--------------------------------
  const fi1 = F(identity).compose(f1);
  /* ts(2345) error
    Argument of type '(a: number) => number' is not assignable to parameter of type '(b: unknown) => number'.
        Types of parameters 'a' and 'b' are incompatible.
          Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'number'.
    const f1: (a: number) => number
  */
}
```

In this sample code, we have 3 basic functions; `f1`, `f2` and `identity`.

`F` is the function that is to extend a specified function to have a method for function composition.

**I managed to make it work somehow; however I found there are 2 issues at least.**

**1.**

Now, we use `F` for `f2`, and the type of `F2` is `((a: number) => string) & F` that is to be expected.

Then, we use `F` for `f1`, and compose with `f2`, and the type of `F12` is also `((a: number) => string) & F` that is to be expected.

Therefore, the type of `F2` and `F12` is identical, so far, so good.

Now, The type of `(F2).compose(identity)` is `((a: number) => string) & F` that is to be expected.

However, the type of `(F12).compose(identity)` is `((a: number) => number) & F` that is Not to be expected.

I have traced my code for a long time, but I have no idea why this thing happens.

Can you give me advice? Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Please note **the functions should not be wrapped in Object**, and my intension is to **provide a compose method Directly to the functions**:

```
 const f = (a: number) => a + 1;
  const fg = f.compose(g);

  //not
  {
    f: f,
      compose:someFunction
  }
```

---

**EDIT: for the #2 issue, with the comments by @jcalz, I created the separate question:**

**[Is there any workaround for ts(2345) error for TypeScript lacks higher kinded types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69793496/is-there-any-workaround-for-ts2345-error-for-typescript-lacks-higher-kinded-ty)**

**2.**

As illustrated, I have **ts(2345) error**, and the error message does not make sense to me so that I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: I realize that the question is about inference, but what's wrong with explicitly passing the generics? `const fi1 = F<number, number>(identity).compose(f1);` type-checks just fine....

Comment: Your two issues should probably be two separate questions.  Your first issue is that you define `F`'s `compose()` method to return the same type `F` as itself, which means every subsequent link in the chain will still expect the callback to take the original `U` type.  If you want to do the chaining correctly you need to do something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbdX9w) instead.

Comment: Your second issue is that TypeScript lacks higher kinded types of the sort necessary to express what you're trying to do; and although some [support](//github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30215) exists for similar operations, you can't do it here with a returned generic function which also has other properties.  So this is not possible and you will need to manually specify parameters.

Comment: The question is: which one of these two things is your question really about?  I'm happy to answer one of them, but the only thing relating the two together is that you ran into both problems with the same bit of code.  If you make this question about one thing, I'll answer it with an explanation.  And you should feel free to ask a separate question about the other thing.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for your input every time, and you always improved my code a lot! Really appreciated.. Then, obviously, you already have solved my issue of #1 with the playground code in your first comment, so I would like to ask for the issue of #2 to be answered. Thanks!

Comment: The answer to #2 is unfortunately "this is impossible".  If you want me to elaborate on that I can, but I think the answer to #1 is more fun because it has the benefit of being solvable.  Anyway, if you really want #2, you should [edit] your question so that it starts with the code where #1 is already solved, and not mention that problem at all.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks again. (1) I edited my question to focus on the #1 question.

Comment: (2) I created a new question:  [Is there any workaround for ts(2345) error for TypeScript lacks higher kinded types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69793496/is-there-any-workaround-for-ts2345-error-for-typescript-lacks-higher-kinded-ty)  >if you really want #2, you should edit your question so that it starts with the code where #1 is already solved

Comment: I'm sorry it was not clarified.. Please note **the functions should not be wrapped in Object**, and my intension is to **provide a compose method Directly to the functions**: See EDIT. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having should be apparent if you inspect the type of `const F` (the value, not the privately-named type) and unroll it a bit:

```
const alsoF: <T, U>(f: (a: T) => U) =>
  ((a: T) => U) & {
    compose: <V>(g: (b: U) => V) => (((a: T) => V) & {
      compose: <V>(g: (b: U) => V) => (((a: T) => V) & {
        compose: <V>(g: (b: U) => V) => (((a: T) => V) & {
          compose: <V>(g: (b: U) => V) => (((a: T) => V) & {
            compose: <V>(g: (b: U) => V) => (((a: T) => V) & any);
          });
        });
      });
    });
  } = F; // okay
```

(I bailed out with `any` after a few levels deep, but you don't need to do that if you create new named types; it doesn't matter for this discussion, though.)  If the function you pass to `F` is of type `(a: T) => U` for some `U`, the returned function has a `compose` method accepts a callback whose first parameter is of type `U`.  That's fine, but then when you call the `compose` method of that, your new thing's `compose` method is of the same type as the old one.  It wants a callback whose parameter is of type `U`. But you wanted a callback whose parameter is of type `V`, the return type of the callback previously passed to `compose()`.  And this problem persists forever: each call to `compose()` will return another thing whose `compose()` expects a callback  accepting a parameter of type `U` and not the return type of the previous call to `compose()`.

So that means your `F(f1)` returns the following type:

```
const fF1 = alsoF(f1);
/* const alsoF12: ((a: number) => string) & {
compose: <V>(g: (b: number) => V) => ((a: number) => V) & {
    compose: <V>(g: (b: number) => V) => ((a: number) => V) & {
        ...;
    };
}; } */
```

And your `F12` is therefore of the following type:

```
const alsoF12 = alsoF(f1).compose(f2);
/* const alsoF12: ((a: number) => string) & {
compose: <V>(g: (b: number) => V) => ((a: number) => V) & {
    compose: <V>(g: (b: number) => V) => ((a: number) => V) & { ... };
};  } */
```

And oops, it will always expect the callback to `compose()` to take a `number`, not a `string` like you want.  And so your `f12i` is this:

```
const alsoF12i = (alsoF12).compose(identity);
/* const alsoF12i: ((a: number) => number) & {
compose: <V>(g: (b: number) => V) => ((a: number) => V) & {
    compose: <V>(g: (b: number) => V) => ((a: number) => V) & { ...  };
  }; } */
```

And that's not what you want.

---

To fix this, you will need the type returned from `compose()` to keep track of both the `T` type from the original callback parameter, and the "current" `U` type which is the return type of the most recently passed-in parameter.  So the `F` type you defined should be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in `U` in order to represent this.  Let's pull it out of the function implementation and describe `F<T, U>` as what comes of out a call to `F(f)` where `f` is of type `(a: T) => U`:

```
interface F<T, U> {
  (a: T): U;
  compose<V>(g: (b: U) => V): F<T, V>;
}
```

So it has a [call signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#call-signatures) which takes a value of type `T` and returns `U`.  It also has a generic `compose` method that takes a callback of type `(b: U) => V` for generic `V`, and returns an `F<T, V>`.  It is this substitution of `V` for `U` that lets the chain keep track of the most recent callback return type.

And here's the implementation:

```
const F = <T, U>(f: (a: T) => U): F<T, U> => {
  return Object.defineProperty(f, "compose", {
    configurable: true,
    value: <V,>(g: (b: U) => V) => F((a: T) => g(f(a)))
  }) as any;
};
```

And let's try it out:

```
const f1 = (a: number) => a + 1;
const f2 = (a: number) => a.toString();
const identity = <T,>(a: T) => a;
//--------------------------------
const F2 = F(f2);
// const F2: F<number, string> 
const F12 = F(f1).compose(f2);
// const F12: F<number, string>
//--------------------------------
const F2i = (F2).compose(identity);
// const F2i: F<number, string>
const f12i = (F12).compose(identity);
// const f12i: F<number, string>

console.log(f12i(123).repeat(2)) // "124124"
```

Looks good. The compiler understands now that `f12i` is of type `F<number, string>` so when you call it, it will return a `string`.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5ATgSwOZIN4Cgk9Cil4B7YKAFyQDEkBeJAHgBUAaJAVQD4AKAGYAuJPxCi2ASia8eMxnIKlS1AJ4xkDZspWkKYGOSgRRLAGpcBWUfwBGo7grnnnY-uMlvXSAGT0pAG4SFQBfYJDSNAhqAFc0YFQ7ACsIeGoAOgATCEEMYAgABTRyTTR1IS4AIgMjEyquXT0ySjyseJA7ABtTJGo0WIgOSJUANxAuwbNLa1sHeVkkH0V6DwkkaUWsIXEpPZGkUJkQKHd1zZWnP3p8W7CIlQoqWgmocjozTh4BETFztyuigOay8iyu-iaelqxl6Fis-BsYnmgJcbg8ng23hkEIOj3Ihhh03hiPsjixi3R-0WPhxzWa0JMRKQsyRZOpaJBmPZ10hdP0+LqsMszIRczZK2WckpoIl2OIfL5DKFxLFC1lFM5F1R1xAwDUQVxdKOwQVpGNhqI5r5Vr0oSY9ECSAA9E6kOQANYgNR3UgulrPeifLh8IS2KmXDnhuTgm4+ogugC0SeTKdTafTKciTxoSEEAEZ7RjgLEwHYIGg3CAkABqJB5k38gOCABMhfWxdL5crGWo5AAyv18tsDXiAxgcsBqBh1Pb2BwBFGkCAG-GnRn1xvU1nKDm6K3mHQhM2R77XZyO2WK4saJhgFg5Qxna6sORyFltwG6Hn96t81IMkqR4nquZyiBeXbXoOd4PiBL5vpEiabkhGYfruzYYIWe7-oB44QJO076iuT6gUg4FXisN5DjBxFwe+o45vm6GYd+2ECjC-C4fh6jAcR54lpebhkdRfp2CAWREAA7gAFmoAD8sm3KhtCCF+9qvO8Qh5jxToAFT+jm6lfs2thFvxEEUVB948tuBKMqw5gsqSpFmeR2orHxnauUscq8vytlCo58xCdy7mmZ55K0qaSAZDFRH3JE4QJUgOlOnG+kvF0bxGWpmUaX+AFsSYQFEbp6VLrlRkme2LluJR0HWXi-nTIFYE1SFUphQJ3KRfShUBaKrLOeF7UkcF6o9QqSrNQNTljW5HXVcN43ylFjWCtNJJBW16orLqahxUaB2WkRiVhMlqX0RlWXfhhzDiBVLEFf5HETlO3ElXp2ZXe8N1Va1S1yMFE1TfZLVDV1O0Lf9EPahNa2EqDM1bQD3kaotMOo3DdIgxYYNzaju16kdhwHadZrnYpPqhPg1P4KAkCwAgyAAFLwBMABexAkPk1DloITP0HO3wrUQGLSI4RFKrjSPiqioh0ELDkNrTRBffQs5fCGvxiwCUjy0LfCLJC0RxAkSSpOk2S5PkRQlGUFSCNUSoNCLjZtB03S9P0gzDM04yTMqYMogTciHjrWw7CAexSAlxynHtysPGV+ZttD5lyFWtb1iQastqn4Pp0uPb9pZ-AnmrnFvWoGvzuHu0NohyFN8mOc7rQe72oeLYnn6at7vrZFcHVWByK3n7fp3mmsc93cN66fffgPLlD5ZvAkI3zdN2PaG3WIWFPYKL14VXPfz239DoUvnkr7eI-b8pN3MceB-sZXBGn8nv2C4PSDD2v2-kB6BkLo5BtiMQwPwb8ABmf80RNAgGoPwY8Mg-RVG-AAFgwVUSmtMgA)

Comment: Thanks a lot! and very sorry for my response is delayed. I will study your answer.

Comment: Again, your answer is extremely elaborated and informative, I study your code and really appreciated.

Comment: After working on your elaborated answer, when I tried to comment out `(a: T): U;` in the `interface F<T, U>` then found some type-checks failed on complicated code, so I know it's really necessary. However I have no idea why and how it works so because that `a` is not referred from any place. Can you advice me? Thanks!

Comment: It's the [call signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#call-signatures); if you want `F<T, U>` to be callable like a function then you need a call signature.  When you say `a` is not referred to, that seems to be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60114432/why-do-i-have-to-specify-parameter-names-in-a-ts-function-type maybe?  In any case it's out of scope of the original question so if you have further questions you probably want to create a new post.  I can't necessarily commit to doing too much followup in comments alone (especially due to character lim

Comment: Thanks!! again. So now I figured out when we see JavaScript functions as object, we need to type call signature property as dafault.  When we have a function: `((a: A) => B)` to have a property,  `{ (a: A): B  }`  should be the base?

Comment: Any way, it's enough information. Thanks for the comment of question.