# Is there any workaround for ts(2345) error for TypeScript lacks higher kinded types?

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, function-composition

Related to my previous question:

[Type inference of Function composition method (chain) in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69791306/type-inference-of-function-composition-method-chain-in-typescript?noredirect=1#comment123366069_69791306)

I try to implement a function that is to extend a specified function to have **a chainable method for [function composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69791306/type-inference-of-function-composition-method-chain-in-typescript?noredirect=1#comment123366069_69791306)**; as below;

Also see:
**[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-GuzYtu655kK8ADMAAsACsdBpsy7jukm3olhi4C6MAQA)**

```
type F<T, U> = {
  (a: T): U;
  "compose": <V>(g: (b: U) => V) => F<T, V>;
};

const F = <T, U>(f: (a: T) => U): F<T, U> =>
  Object.defineProperty(f, "compose", {
    configurable: true,
    value: <V,>(g: (b: U) => V) => F((a: T) => g(f(a)))
  }) as any;

const f1 = (a: number) => a + 1;
const f2 = (a: number) => a.toString();
const identity = <T,>(a: T) => a;
//--------------------------------
const F2 = F(f2);
// const F2: F<number, string>
const F12 = F(f1).compose(f2);
// const F12: F<number, string>
//--------------------------------
const F2i = (F2).compose(identity);
// const F2i: F<number, string>
const F12i = (F12).compose(identity);
// const F12i: F<number, string>

const fi1 = F(identity).compose(F2);
/*
Argument of type 'F<number, string>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(b: unknown) => string'.
  Types of parameters 'a' and 'b' are incompatible.
    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2345)
const F2: F<number, string>
*/
```

[image]

As illustrated, I have **ts(2345) error**, and that is according to @jcalz;

> Your second issue is that TypeScript lacks higher kinded types of the sort necessary to express what you're trying to do; and although some [support](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30215) exists for similar operations, you can't do it here with a returned generic function which also has other properties. So this is not possible and you will need to manually specify parameters.

> The answer to #2 is unfortunately "this is impossible".

[Higher order function type inference #30215](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30215)

Having said that, is there any workaround?

Comment: Please take a look here https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/HKT.ts.html#hkt-interface

Comment: @captain-yossarian Thanks! I noticed that before, but now I think I really need to study the project.

Comment: believe me, you will not find a better workaround

Comment: I don't know if that type of HKT will work for this anyway, and even if it does it would require so much more effort than just calling `F<number, number>(identity).compose(f1)` to guide the compiler into seeing `identity` as transforming `number` to `number`.  Any workaround I can think of is worse than such manual specification.

Comment: @jcalz I meant workaround for HKT

Comment: @captain-yossarian since your comment, I studied the HKT workaround a lot. Thanks.

Comment: @Functor, thanks. I have noticed  that you have a lof of questions regarding FP. Looking forward to see your code examples. Are working on a library?

Comment: @captain-yossarian Sorry for late reply. Here's my refactored new question with my current refactored code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69876135/typescript-is-type-predicates-user-defined-type-guard-functions-to-implement   Please investigate my new code and point me out the problem. Thanks as always! and Yes, it's sort of a simple library.