# What is superior or preferred about this style of function declaration syntax?

Tags: typescript

I'm attempting to contribute to a project and I've noticed a function declaration syntax that I don't understand, or at least I don't appreciate the value of it.
Here is the syntax:

```
export const getRecordById: (number) => number| undefined = (id: number) => {
  return id + 1  //  not real logic
}
```

I interpret that as `getRecordById` is declared as a function type that takes a single `number` parameter and returns either a `number` type or `undefined`. It is assigned to a function with a number parameter named `id`

If I've got that right, I would write that function like this:

```
export function getRecordById(id: number): number| undefined {
  return id + 1  //  not real logic
}
```

My question is, what is the value in the more verbose and, to me, cryptic syntax in the first example? I suspect there **IS** a reason, but I don't understand or know it.
What am I missing?

Comment: One is an arrow function assigned to a variable and the other is a function statement; do you understand the difference between those in JavaScript?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/mAj18W) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: This is *almost* a duplicate of [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname), but none of the answers there seem to talk about using `const` in this pattern. Nonetheless, the answer to this is basically the answer to that, plus "`const` declarations can't be reassigned accidentally".

Comment: @jcalz I have a basic understanding of the differences, but not much experience working with them. In my example I should have used ```export const getRecordById = function (id: number): number| undefined``` The reason to use arrow function isn't apparent. I'll keep looking into it. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: When you say "I should have used", do you want to [edit] it?  Right now `(number) => number | undefined` is problematic because it [doesn't mean what you think it means](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60114432/2887218).  Either you need something like `(id: number) => number | undefined` instead, or you should edit the question to use the `function` expression instead of the arrow function.  Let me know once the question stabilizes.

Answer (score -1):

The preferred style is the one the project is mostly made of. If they established a code standard of exporting arrow functions instead of exporting `function` then the most sensible approach is to use the arrow functions, because of consistency.

Having said that... in this particular case I would go with the function, because it's less cryptic.